# Force cache already cached dataset spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

I have cached a hive table in a dataset (Dataset<Row> in Java, Dataframe in Scala).

I want to keep refreshing this dataset periodically. But when I trigger the cache again, it says :

```
Asked to cache already cached data.
```

And hence it doesn't cache it. I want to forcefully cache this data into another dataset.

Also, I cannot unpersist the earlier cached data as I cannot make the cached data unavailable for the time second caching is taking place. I am fine with the double memory consumption when both the caches are present. Once the second one is completed, I will unpersist the first one.

Adding some code for reference below :

```
private static Dataset<Row> primaryDataset;
private static Dataset<Row> secondaryDataset;

private static boolean primaryInd = false;
...
...
public void cacheDataset(SparkSession spark){

    
    String query = "select * from db.table";

    if(primaryInd){

        secondaryDataset = spark.sql(query);

        secondaryDataset.cache();

        long count = secondaryDataset.count();
        logger.info(">>> Dataset is Cached. Count = " + count);

        primaryInd = false;
        primaryDataset.unpersist();

    }else {

        primaryDataset = spark.sql(query);

        primaryDataset.cache();

        long count = primaryDataset.count();
        logger.info(">>> Dataset is Cached. Count = " + count);

        primaryInd = true;

        try {
            secondaryDataset.unpersist();
        }catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException){
            logger.info(">>> Null Pointer exception while unpersisting. Could be the first caching.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hard to follow without seeing some code. pls post.

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom, Added some code for reference, hope this helps.

Comment: try 2 query strings

Comment: Are you sure in your actual code that primaryInd is updated?

Comment: saw no issue. may be the comment made is valid